# What is the default ArgoCD ignored differences

Tags: kubernetes, devops, argocd

I need to know the ArgoCD list of changes in k8s object yamls that is by default ignored - meaning that, when this k8s key:value is changed in yaml the argocd will remain synced.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing from rendered your manifest will be ignored unless you specifically list them in your application configuration:

Read more here:

- https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/diffing/
- https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-options/#respect-ignore-difference-configs